# NextJS gives an error during the build step in Docker when trying to connect to strapi api

Tags: docker, next.js, strapi

I am trying to run nextjs with strapi by using docker. NextJS app is giving an error during the npm packages build step like this:

```
request to http://localhost:1337/api/categories?fields%5B0%5D=slug failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

I tried to change localhost to strapi but it didn't help too.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: postgres
      DATABASE_NAME: strapi
      DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_USERNAME: strapi
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./api:/srv/api
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - strapi_app

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: strapi
      POSTGRES_USER: strapi
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapi
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" 
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - strapi_app
    
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
    networks: 
      - strapi_app
    depends_on:
      - strapi

networks:
  strapi_app:
    driver: bridge
```

I created a network for the services in docker-compose.yaml file. They should run in the same network. I couldn't realize what I am missing.

Also I couldn't find any effective solution from stackoverflow or google search.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think you should not use localhost use  `http://strapi/api` instead because you are in a docker container

Comment: I tried this also. It didn't help me @Antoni

Comment: Remove networks it is unnecessary and try it again

Comment: @tcetin did you able to find a solution ?